# view considers navigation bar only after rotation

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a simple UIScrollView

```
UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];

[mainScrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

When the view is loaded and shown, part of UIScrollView appears under the navigation bar. But after rotation the view is suddenly considers navigation bar and pins the view to its bottom.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG1LU.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdwRW.png]

How can I make a view consider navigation bar from the beginning?

Comment: in iOS 8 default navigation bar from the beginning.

Comment: I don't know what did you mean, but, I guess, you don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi,, i get your question but in iOS 8 this is the default. if you are working on iOS 7 then i will try to solve your problem.

Comment: There is no difference. On the both versions behavior is the same.

Comment: Sorry but i have worked on both and in iOS 8 it's defualt.

Answer (score 0):

To start UIScrollView at bottom of UINavigationBar then i would suggest you to set `Adjust Scroll View Insets` property and setting `Extend Edges` property as well. do the needful changes of below property as per your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this issue.

Problem has been solved by moving creation of scrollView to viewDidLoad method. Somehow, if scrollView is created outside the "load" methods, we can face such kind of problems.